# Div container not expanding correctly width-wise with window

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a div container that will expand with the window. Here is a general outline of my HTML:

```html
<main class="flex-shrink-0">
<div class="parent">
   <div class="row full-border rounded">
      <div class="bg-white">
         <div class="row justify-content-center">
            Content Here!
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
...
</main>
```

And the CSS:

```css
.parent{
   width: 90vw;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

On initial load everything looks nice and clean. The behavior while expanding the window is that the left edge will stay mostly stationary, adding some extra space to the left of it, but the right edge expands out of sight as the container tries to maintain that `90vw`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use percentages instead of viewport unit

something like this should do

```css
.parent{
   width: 90%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```